# SUM in asp .net report viewer based on condition

Tags: asp.net, sql, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

I have table =>

```
Main Table  : MT
================
PK SPK Name D1 
==============
1, 0, XYZ, 0
1, 1, A, 99
1, 2, B, 88
1, 3, C, 77
2, 0, NULL, 0
2, 1, NULL, 99
2, 2, Z, 88
```

Now, both database and report viewer is ***exactly*** showing above pattern.
I want SUM of D1 in first row for each PK where SPK=0.
To display D1 fields in report viewer I tried this

```
=IIF(Fields!SPK.Value=0,SUM(Fields!D1.Value),Fields!D1.Value)
```

But I am wrong here. In report viewer also I am getting same above displayed table.
I want the total of all Values where SPK is 0 for every PK in First row. But I do not get the first row as Total where SPK=0.
Also, D1 is always 0 where SPK=0 from database for which row I want to display SUM.

**Any way to get the SUM of D1 in first row instead of 0 where SPK=0?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get sum of d1 in query and then it use in report

```
SELECT PK, SPK, NAME, CASE WHEN SPK = 0 THEN SUM(D1) OVER(PARTITION BY PK) ELSE D1 END AS D1 MT
```